# If $X_n \sim U[0,1]$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $X:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \prod_{i=1}^n X_i$ Show that $\mathbb{E}[X] < \infty$

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

> Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of independet random variables with $X_n \sim U[0,1]$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and define $$X:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \prod_{i=1}^n X_i$$
> Show that $\mathbb{E}[X] < \infty$

First i define $Y_n:=\prod_{i=1}^n |X_i|$ then $Y_n \geq 0, \forall n$ and
$$ \mathbb{E}[Y_n]=\mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i=1}^n |X_i| \right]=\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[|X_i|]=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2^n} $$
Where the second equality follows from the independence of the $X_i$ and the third equality follows because $$\mathbb{E}[|X_i|]=\mathbb{E}[X_i]$$
since $X_i \sim U[0,1]$ and hence

$$\mathbb{E} \left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} Y_n \right]= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[Y_n]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}=1$$
But from these calculations I am not sure how to conclude, any hint or help i will be very grateful.

Comment: All you need to know is that $1<\infty$, since you computation gives $$\mathbf{E}[X]=\mathbf{E}\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_n\right]=1<\infty.$$

Comment: Sure¡  im litle confused because i cant see the fact that $E[X]=E\left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_n \right]$

Comment: Tonelli's Theorem allows you to switch expectation and infinite sum.

Comment: Since $X_n\sim\mathcal{U}[0,1]$ for each $n$, we know that $X_n\geq 0$ for all $n$ almost surely. This gives $Y_n=\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ a.s. and hence $X=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_n$. Alternatively, note that the triangle inequality gives $$|X|\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_i\right|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_n$$ and hence $$\mathbf{E}[|X|]\leq\mathbf{E}\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_n\right]=1<\infty.$$

Comment: @SangchulLee ohh i see¡ im not considerer the fact that $X_n \geq 0$ a.s, thanks¡¡

Answer (score 1):

$E(\log X_1)=-1$ therefore from the law of large numbers $$Y_n^{1/n}=(X_1\ldots X_n)^{1/n}\rightarrow e^{-1}<1$$ which implies $\sum_1^{\infty}Y_n<\infty$ almost surely from Cauchy criteria. The expectation of $\sum_1^{\infty}Y_n$ is $1$ as correctly explained in other answers.

However,  the point above is necessary : if $\Pr(Y_n=1/n)=1/n$ and $\Pr(Y_n=0)=(n-1)/n$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E(Y_n)<\infty$ while by Borel Cantelli $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_n=\infty.$

Comment: If $Y_n\geq0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbf{E}[Y_n]<\infty$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_n$ converges a.s. I guess you intended $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbf{1}_{\{Y_n>0\}}=\infty$ a.s. or something along this line.

Comment: Thank you, my mistake!